# Suppress Draw method increase cpu usage

Tags: c#, xna, cpu, xna-4.0

My main Update loop is like this:

```
public ovveride void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    if (!paused)
    {
         // Do a lot of clever things
    }
    else
    {
         SuppressDraw();
    }

    // Function to check mouse input
    PauseButton.Update(gametime);
}
```

I noticed, using Windows' task manager, that when I **ENABLE pause**, CPU usage of my application goes from a min-max of 2%-4% to a min-max of 30%-34%.

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing whats in your SupressDraw function.

Comment: This isn't my method :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.suppressdraw.aspx

Comment: What is IsFixedTimeStep set to?  When it is *false*, your Update() method will be called a lot more often, thus burning core.

Comment: It does this in both cases!

Comment: I have discovered this same problem. Thought I was being clever and saving my CPU by using SuppressDraw() and drawing only when there has been a change. This is bizarrely not the case. Any insight on this yet?